# Reuse function call inside select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Simplified example of the problem:

```
select p.id,
       p.name,
       -- other columns from joined tables
       decode(get_complicated_number(p.id), null, null, "The number is: " || get_complicated_number(p.id)))
from some_table p
-- join other tables and WHERE clause
```

It includes `get_complicated_number` call which queries multiple tables. I wasn't able to write it as a JOIN statement that would be as fast and as easy to maintain as a separate function so far.

Currently the function is called twice in case its return value is not NULL.

In reality I have an XML generation package that gets the data with a select:

```
select distinct  xmlAgg
  (
     xmlelement
     (
      "TestElement", 
        xmlelement("Id", p.id),
        xmlelement("Name", p.name),
        -- other elements from joined tables
        decode(get_complicated_number(p.id), null, null, xmlelement("ComplicatedNum", get_complicated_number(p.id)))
      )
   )
from some_table p
-- join other tables and WHERE clause
```

Is there a way to make it only one call and still avoid creating an empty element on NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user7294900's answer is good, but if it's hard to combine with your existing joins, here's an alternate version with an inline view instead of a CTE.

```
select distinct  xmlAgg
  (
     xmlelement
     (
      "TestElement", 
        xmlelement("Id", p2.id),
        xmlelement("Name", p2.name),
        -- other elements from joined tables
        decode(p2.num, null, null, xmlelement("ComplicatedNum", p2.num))
      )
   )
from (
    select p.id, p.name, get_complicated_number(p.id) as num
    from some_table p
    ) p2
-- join other tables to p2. or put them inside it.
```

If you want help with adding your existing joins to these example queries, you might need to edit your question and add your other tables and WHERE clauses.

Comment: While the other answer is very nice, this one is simpler and easier to read for me. Performance wise they seem mostly the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [WITH Syntax (Common Table Expressions)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html) as:

```
with complicated_number as (
select get_complicated_number(p.id) as num from some_table p
) select distinct  xmlAgg 
--...
decode(complicated_number.num, null, null, xmlelement("ComplicatedNum", complicated_number.num))
from complicated_number
```

> common table expression (CTE) is a named temporary result set that exists within the scope of a single statement and that can be referred to later within that statement, possibly multiple times

Comment: Thank you. As I understand it will calculate the value once in such case, while in my original case it will call for each row of `some_table` that goes into the selection, and have diferent `complicated_number` in each case (XML element).

Comment: @icebat yes, added explanation *single statement and that can be referred to later within that statement, possibly multiple times*

Comment: @icebat each record will execute on different id from original table, did you try?

Comment: Oh, so the whole select will be wrapped in `complicated_number` from the example, basically. Got it at last, much appreciated!